# static void method not being called on iOS 8

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios7, ios8, void

I have the following method working perfectly on iOS6 and iOS7

```
#import "MapaViewController.h"
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "CelulaAlertas.h"  
#import "OBRadar.h"
#import "OBDownloadBase.h"

#define DEG2RAD(degrees) (degrees * 0.01745327) // degrees * pi over 180

static void distanceFunc(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
   // check that we have four arguments (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
    assert(argc == 4);
// check that all four arguments are non-null
   if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[1]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[2]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[3]) == SQLITE_NULL) {
    sqlite3_result_null(context);
    return;
}
// get the four argument values
double lat1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[0]);
double lon1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[1]);
double lat2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[2]);
double lon2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[3]);
// convert lat1 and lat2 into radians now, to avoid doing it twice below
double lat1rad = DEG2RAD(lat1);
double lat2rad = DEG2RAD(lat2);
// apply the spherical law of cosines to our latitudes and longitudes, and set the result appropriately
// 6378.1 is the approximate radius of the earth in kilometres
sqlite3_result_double(context, acos(sin(lat1rad) * sin(lat2rad) + cos(lat1rad) * cos(lat2rad) * cos(DEG2RAD(lon2) - DEG2RAD(lon1))) * 6378.1);
```

}

On my Initial method I call:

```
sqlite3_create_function(db, "distance", 4, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &distanceFunc, NULL, NULL);
```

and on my select:

```
NSString *qsql= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Radares WHERE distance(Latitude, Longitude, %@, %@)<1 ORDER BY distance(Latitude, Longitude, %@, %@)",lat,longi,lat,longi];

NSLog(@"%@",qsql);

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, [qsql UTF8String], -1,
                       &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {.....
```

Only on iOS8 the "distanceFunc" method is not being called.. Can someone help me do understand why?

I am getting two different error codes in sqlite prepare running the same code in iOS 7 and iOS 8:

ios7

2014-09-19 09:18:08.841 Mapa Radar[511:60b] Database returned error 0: not an error
2014-09-19 09:18:08.841 Mapa Radar[511:60b] Database returned error 0: not an error
2014-09-19 09:18:08.974 Mapa Radar[511:60b] Accucary  5
2014-09-19 09:18:08.975 Mapa Radar[511:60b] SELECT * FROM Radares WHERE distance2(Latitude, Longitude, -23.111100, -46.849126)<1 ORDER BY distance2(Latitude, Longitude, -23.111100, -46.849126)
2014-09-19 09:18:08.975 Mapa Radar[511:60b] Database returned error 0: not an error

ios8

2014-09-19 09:14:51.631 Mapa Radar[609:76761] Database returned error 0: not an error
2014-09-19 09:14:51.633 Mapa Radar[609:76761] Database returned error 0: not an error
2014-09-19 09:14:52.252 Mapa Radar[609:76761] Accucary 65
2014-09-19 09:14:52.258 Mapa Radar[609:76761] SELECT * FROM Radares WHERE distance2(Latitude, Longitude, -23.516678, -47.477784)<1 ORDER BY distance2(Latitude, Longitude, -23.516678, -47.477784)
2014-09-19 09:14:52.259 Mapa Radar[609:76761] Database returned error 0: not an error
2014-09-19 09:14:52.261 Mapa Radar[609:76761] Database returned error 1: no such table: Radares

Why on iOS 8, my table Radares is not being recognized but on iOS 6 and 7 it works?

Comment: 1) Check the return value of `sqlite3_create_function` to make sure the function is created. 2) Is the inside of the `while` loop being reached when running your query?

Comment: The function is not being created but only on iOS8.. the code inside "static void distanceFunc" doesn't run on iOS8.. on debug mode I checked it..

Comment: What's the return value from `sqlite3_create_function`?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question, but it should create the sqlite function "distance" that I use onde the SELECT, in the WHERE clause.. WHERE distance(Latitude, Longitude, %@, %@).. this function compares the 30.000 Latitude and Longitude points that I have on my table with the user's position and the result I check if it is less than 1KM... I got this method on this link: http://daveaddey.com/?p=71

Comment: What rmaddy is saying is that **sqlite3_create_function had a return code!!**  What value is being returned??  `int sqlite3_create_function(...` -- the `int` is a return code.  You should **always** check SQLite return codes.

Comment: Sorry Hot Licks, maybe I am being stupid here, but there isn't "int sqlite3_create_function(", Can you explain me please how can i get this return code then? thanks

Comment: **READ [THE DOCUMENTATION](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)!!**  sqlite3_create_function is not a `void` function -- it returns a value.  **What is that value?????????**

Comment: The docs say that 0 is OK, right? so it seems that the problem is on the &distanceFunc... the funny thing is that when I put a breakpoint inside the distanceFunc in iOS7 I see the code running, but on iOS8 it doesn't run..

Comment: Guys, any ideas on that?

Comment: I'm wondering if there isn't another "distance" method defined.  Try changing its name.

Comment: Also, what return codes are you getting from prepare and step?

Comment: Hot Licks, I have edited my post and included the logs for sqlite_prepare... I have changed the name of the distance method but the problem persists.. the weird thing is the sqlite_prepare giving me different behavior on ios7 and ios8..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:

I download the base from a server an save in a file on the Documents directory. Until iOS7 the method that I used to create de file path to save the base was ok, but apparently on iOS8 it isn't.. it was saving a empty database..

So i used another method to create the path to documents:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
NSMutableString *fileName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@/radares.db",
                             documentsDirectory];


NSLog(@"%@",fileName);

[_dados writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```